# Unable to populate drop down using html,php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Below code is used to create a payment form.

Everything works fine but problem is in `supplier-ID` `dropdown`.

Drop down is created but does not fetch data from `mysql` table and also shows no error.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body bgcolor="Silver">

<form name="info" action="payment.php" method="post"><br />
<h3><b>Payment</b></h3><br/>

Payment Date<br/>
<input type="date" name="paymt_dt" /><br />
Payment#<br/>
<input type="text" name="paymt_no" maxlength="6"/><br />
Supplier ID<br />
<select name="sup_id">
<?php
    include_once 'func.inc.php';
    connect();
$sql="select sup_id,sup_name from supplier ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['sup_id'];?>"> <?php echo $line['sup_name'];?> </option>

<?php
}
?>
</select><br />

Payment Mode<br />
<select name="pmt_mod">
    <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
    <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
    <option value="DD">DD</option>
    <option value="Payord">Pay Order</option>
</select><br />
Document#<br/>
<input type="text" name="doc_no" maxlength="15"/><br />
Document Date<br/>
<input type="date" name="doc_dt" /><br />
Amount<br />
<input type="number" name="amount" maxlength="10" /><br />
Remarks<br/>
<textarea id="txt1" name="remarks" maxlength="100" rows="4" cols="50">Type your comments here</textarea><br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say 'it shows no error', have got [error reporting turned on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)?

Comment: try to do this after the query runs `echo mysql_error();` this will give you any warnings and mysql error.

Comment: and also check if the query returns empty rows.

Comment: in php.ini I found that "display_error=on" already exists.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli instead. and in while loop

```
while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 // rest of the code }
```